# List of same components with same functions - code bloat?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue and I wonder if I have a list of components (50 button with the very same function within each one of them) - will Vue recognize it as a repetetive code and reduce to one function that all those 50 button will use or each one will compile it's own function while bundling?

Comment: no, vue does not have ai built in. If they do the same thing, make a component and use a v-for. If you want more of an answer please provide more details/code snippets

Comment: If they're all repeating the same function you should consider using a [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) instead

Answer (score 2):

> will Vue recognize it as a repetetive code and reduce to one..

No. Vue will not scan your code for similar code and try to optimize it.

However, when Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with v-for, by default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index.

Maybe this is what you are confused with? This is not the same as the question you are asking, but the closest thing vue would do "magically".

If you have 50 similar buttons, I would advice you to rather take advantage of [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html), [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) and [slot scopes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) to only have one button component that you can tweek in place where you need them to be different. 50 alike buttons sounds like a bad pattern.

Comment: Th thing with buttons is this: they are the same visually and have the same function. The only thing they differ is id they us within the function. As of now I use slots and props so function is hold by the parent, but that limits my options (I don't have full control over button).